# can graphviz group output of svg

Tags: svg, graphviz

I have the following .dot file for graphviz

```
digraph example {

    node [fontsize=24, shape = plaintext];

    1940 -> 1950;
    1950 -> 1955;
    1955 -> 1960;
 
 
    node [fontsize=20, shape = box];
    { rank=same;  1940 test; }
    { rank=same;  1955 test; }

}
```

The svg it outputs looks like the following

```
<g id="node1" class="node">
<title>1940</title>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="32.5" y="-803.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="24.00">1940</text>
</g>
<!-- 1950 -->
<g id="node2" class="node">
<title>1950</title>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="32.5" y="-731.8" font-family="Times New Roman,serif" font-size="24.00">1950</text>
</g>
```

and so forth.

I would like to output a  around a group of nodes. So if for example if was possible to do something like this in the graphviz code

```
node [fontsize=20, shape = box, group = boxes];
{ rank=same;  1940 test; }
{ rank=same;  1955 test; }
```

and then when you output the svg it would wrap all of those nodes inside of a

```
<g id="boxes">...</g>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to either of:
https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/
http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/
for a place to play around.

Examples:
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/tools/Graphviz/examples/index

Manual:
https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html  *or even*
https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf

FAQ:
https://graphviz.org/faq/

Forum:
https://forum.graphviz.org/

FWIW: Inkscape does not accept you your "SVG".
A version downloaded from GraphvizOnline has a lot more content.

If you wish to have your nodes inside a box (at the end) you might be successful using a `subgraph {}` as shown below.
*My attempts at using rankdir to have 1950 and 1960 nodes placed vertically seems futile though ;-)*

```
digraph example {

subgraph cluster_P {
    
    node [fontsize=14, shape = plaintext];

    1940 -> 1950;
    1950 -> 1955;
    1955 -> 1960;
 
    { rank=same; rankdir=TB;  1960 1950 }
    { rank=same; rankdir=LR;  1940  1955 }
   
  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  The **group** attribute has meaning within Graphviz, but is not passed on the the svg output.  There are other ways to pass values on to SVG: (**cluster**, **comment**, **class**, **id** attributes) but none do what you are asking for.  Additionally, there is no guarantee that the nodes will be output contiguously.
You can use the **id** attribute to mark *each* node with the same value.  Like so:

```
digraph Y{

a b c

node [fontsize=20 shape = box  id=POOL];

{ rank=same;  1940 testA; }
{ rank=same;  1955 testB; }
1940->1955 [style=inviz]

}
```

p.s. **rankdir** only applies to the Root graph.